# GoogleMaps is not a dylib , Compile time error with pod file on latest version

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, google-maps

[image]Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSServices", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.GMSServices in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: How are you handling your dependencies? Pod?

Comment: i just follow all the instruction given on :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#get-cocoapods

Comment: Please check this 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/j0hCG.png

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are building for the arm64bit and the Google Maps SDK doesnt have a 64 bit version.

Try building for armv7, armv7s only

If this do not solve your purpose check the framework list required to integrate GoogleMaps.

Comment: I think there is some problem with pod installation as just now I integrated GoogleMaps it is working fine.

Comment: Please check https://youtu.be/dS6UwD51EGg here I have posted how to implement GoogleMaps with pods.

Comment: Hi, Reshmi Please See the query regarding this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154835/error-when-i-upgrade-static-googlemap-sdk-to-cocoapods