# Auto-Linking supplied ... GooglePlaces and GoogleMapsBase ... not a dylib

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-places, eureka-forms

I'm integrating [GooglePlacesRow](https://github.com/EurekaCommunity/GooglePlacesRow), an extension of Eureka framework, into my app using CocoaPods. GooglePlaces and GoogleMapsBase frameworks are supposed to be included inside GooglePlacesRow/Frameworks, so what I need to do is just simly tell Xcode where those frameworks are by adding `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Pods/GooglePlacesRow/Frameworks` to `Build Settings/Framework Search Paths` as pointed out in the instruction.

However, I still get the following warnings:

```
Auto-Linking supplied '.../Pods/GooglePlacesRow/Frameworks/GoogleMapsBase.framework/GoogleMapsBase', framework linker option at .../Pods/GooglePlacesRow/Frameworks/GoogleMapsBase.framework/GoogleMapsBase is not a dylib

Auto-Linking supplied '.../Pods/GooglePlacesRow/Frameworks/GooglePlaces.framework/GooglePlaces', framework linker option at .../Pods/GooglePlacesRow/Frameworks/GooglePlaces.framework/GooglePlaces is not a dylib
```

I already checked out these [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152442/what-is-causing-this-crashlytics-compile-warning-auto-linking-supplied-f) and [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34988942/googlemaps-is-not-a-dylib-compile-time-error-with-pod-file-on-latest-version) but my case is a bit different as I should not have to manually import GooglePlaces and GoogleMapsBase libraries again. Am I right?